# Parse pasted images from Outlook emails as attachments in Sharepoint list

Tags: 2010, email, splistitem, incoming-email

I have a Sharepoint list with incoming email enabled, and an email event receiver to create items out of incoming emails. Once an email is received, it sends an email back to the sender with the contents as a confirmation.

You can send an attachment and the receiver will add the attachment to the list item, but most users paste screenshots into emails instead of attaching saved images (easier).

Is there a way to parse these pasted images and add them to the list item as an attachment?

Comment: Aren't they just embedded as `<img />` tags?

Comment: Yeah but the src is different, eg:

<img width="277" height="588" id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01CD708B.77509FF0" alt="Description: cid:image001.png@01CD7089.09DE0C70">

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a good place to start:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691877/regex-to-find-in-line-images-in-a-plain-text-email-message

Once you can decode the image (look at the example return data here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332400/python-parsing-emails-with-embedded-images) then it's a matter of simply adding the image as an attachment.

One of the big issues you're going to run into is making this work with email from all email clients, as different clients use different formatting.

As far as uploading it as an attachment to the list, see this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334695/sharepoint-how-to-add-an-attachment-to-a-list-item-programatically

And here's the code snippet:

```
foreach (FileInfo attachment in attachments)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(attachment.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    fs.Close();

    item.Attachments.Add(attachment.Name, ImageData); 
}
```

Comment: Cheers, should have checked there first, more of a general outlook thing.

I'm not too concerned about other email clients as it's an internal site and we only use outlook here. I may have to modify it for the outlook web app depending if it formats things differently.

Comment: Asked a more specific question, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784013/parsing-outlook-emails-with-embedded-images-add-to-sharepoint-list-item-as-atta

Comment: Personally, I would break off the SharePoint portions of that other question. You might get barked at for that. SO is a good place to ask about email parsing. This is a good place to ask about SharePoint. I'm going to edit my answer here to include a code sample to upload an attachment to a list item.

Comment: Still having problems with this... Not sure how to go about it.